# Spliced audio auxilliary cable

Tags: wiring, speakers

I spliced a wire with a headphone jack attached, the rubber cable runs two separate wires together (like speaker wire.)

In one there is one coated copper wire and one uncoated copper wire.

In the other, there is one coated green wire and one uncoated copper wire.

Which wires should connect to my speaker positive and negative ports?

Comment: A chord is a thing in music that consists of several notes played simultaneously.  Is is also a thing in geometry (chord of a circle.)  It is also a thing in (house) construction.  It is NOT a thing when discussing wires.  I've fixed your question to reflect the correct terminology.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, cable consist from two coaxial cables together.
Then central wire is positive and "coated" is negative. You have pair of wires, because one pair is for left and second pair for right channel.